# Java 8 Streams map API - interpretation of method reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Sample code:

```
class Outer {
    public Integer i;

    Outer(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getVal() { return i; }
}

class MyClass {

    public Integer f(Outer o) { return o.getVal();};

    public void main() {

        MyClass g = new MyClass();

        List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(new Outer(2)).stream().map(g::f).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(new Outer(2)).stream().map(Outer::getVal).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Using either of the method references of

1. `Outer::instanceMethod` that takes no argument and is basically a `Supplier<T>` functional interface. <sup>[1]</sup>
2. `MyClass::instanceMethod` that takes an argument of type `Outer` and is a `Function<T,R>`functional interface. <sup>[1]</sup>

is valid. Then how does the `map` function know to apply the function in option (1) to the objects of the stream, but pass the stream objects to function in option (2)?

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: In each case, it's the only option which would compile. I am sure the JLS spells it out in detail though I am not sure where.

Comment: Note that outer::instanceMethod is not a Supplier in this case. It's a Function, too. The input of the function is `this` (i.e. the `outer` instance on which the method is called), the output is the value returned by the method.

Comment: @JBNizet I suspected this very behavior. For example, in Python, all class functions pass `this` as the first argument by default, so no function has 'zero' arguments. But where in the docs is this behavior/convention mentioned?

Comment: There, for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type

Comment: As a side note, `Arrays.asList(new outer(2)).stream()` in a very convoluted way of creating a single element stream, wrapping the instance in an array, wrapping the array in a list, to eventually create a Stream from a List. Just use `Stream.of(new outer(2))` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the `map` method does not know itself what to do with method references. That's the compiler's job. In both cases, `map` expects  :

```
Function<? super PackageName.outer,? extends Integer>
```

For you particular question both method references according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) are a *Reference to an instance method of a particular object*

Regarding how the compiler deals with lambdas and method references and translates them to bytecode [this document](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html) is highly recommended reading. The most relevant part to your question (emphasis mine to summarise):

> **When the compiler encounters a lambda expression**, it first lowers
>   (desugars) the lambda body into a method whose argument list and
>   return type match that of the lambda expression, possibly with some
>   additional arguments (for values captured from the lexical scope, if
>   any.) At the point at which the lambda expression would be captured,
>   **it generates an invokedynamic call site, which, when invoked, returns
>   an instance of the functional interface to which the lambda is being
>   converted**. This call site is **called the lambda factory** for a given
>   lambda. The dynamic arguments to the lambda factory are the values
>   captured from the lexical scope. **The bootstrap method of the lambda
>   factory is** a standardized method in the Java language runtime library,
>   **called the lambda metafactory**. The static bootstrap arguments capture
>   information known about the lambda at compile time (the functional
>   interface to which it will be converted, a method handle for the
>   desugared lambda body, information about whether the SAM type is
>   serializable, etc.)
>
> **Method references** are treated the same way as lambda expressions,
>   except that most method references do not need to be desugared into a
>   new method; we can simply **load a constant method handle for the
>   referenced method and pass that to the metafactory**
>
> **Instance-capturing method reference** forms include bound instance
>   method references (s::length, captured with **reference kind
>   invokeVirtual**)

The bytecode for your 2 cases is :

1. `outer::instanceMethod`

   ```
   // handle kind 0x5 : INVOKEVIRTUAL
   PackageName/outer.getVal()I, 
   (LPackageName/outer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   ```
2. `MyClass::instanceMethod`

   ```
   // handle kind 0x5 : INVOKEVIRTUAL
   PackageName/MyClass.f(LPackageName/outer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;, 
   (LPackageName/outer;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   ```

Note that, although the second line is more complicated in the second case, the last line is the same. In both cases the compiler just sees a function that takes an `outer` and returns an `Integer`. And that matches what `map` expects.

Method References are described in the language spec [15.13 Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13). The fact that the target reference of a method reference is an implicit first argument of the method is mentioned at [15.13.3 Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3-400-B).

> If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the target
>   reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method.
>   Otherwise, there is no target reference

Comment: I get it that both functions end up passing an `outer` type object as a parameter. What I wanted to know was whether this behavior is documented anywhere, i.e., for example, the getters of a class implicitly pass the object instance for which they are called. In other words, does the compiler interpret `outer.getValue()` as `outer.getValue(outer this)` in general?

Comment: You could say that the compiler does that in general. I'll add a reference to docs in my answer