# How to use Java 8 Streams to pull a string value out of a list of objects and create a new list?

Tags: java, lambda

I just can't seem to figure this one out after looking at all kinds of examples.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
HashSet<String> oldIds = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<String> newIds = new HashSet<>();

for (Release currentRelease: lastPage.getPage()) {
    oldIds.add(currentRelease.getId()); 
}

for (Release currentRelease: lastPageAgain) { 
    newIds.add(currentRelease.getId()); 
}
```

I know there's a much better way to 'collect' these values into the HashSet:

```
lastPage.getPage().getContent().stream().collect(release::getId());
```

But that doesn't compile unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what `release::getId()` is supposed to do, since `release` isn't a variable you've defined. But if I understand what you want, I think `.forEach(currentRelease::add)` will be it.

Comment: You're totally right - the compiler error is that release is undefined. I think I figured it out though. forEach is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors.

1)`release` is not a variable here.
You have to reference the `Release` class in the method reference.

2) method references have not to specify the parenthesis for the method as you did here : `release::getId()`.
A method reference refers always to a method.
So `()` is indeed implicit.
Besides, a method reference may refer to a method that has parameter(s).
So specifying `()` would be so error prone too.

Just replace `release::getId()` by `release::getId`.

3) `collect()` cannot accept a function such as `release::getId()`.
In its simplest overload form, it expects to have a `Collector`. So pass  `Collectors.toSet()` as argument.

You can simply  use `map()` to map something to something else.
Note that you should favor `Set<String>` to `HashSet<String>` in your code. 
Programming by interface improves the maintainability of your code.
`Collectors.toSet()` follows this principle. So it returns a `Set<String>` declared type.

```
Set<String> oldIds = lastPage.getPage().getContent()
                         .stream()
                         .map(Release::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And do the same thing for `newIds`.

Comment: this is a more concise version of what I came up with with just forEach. I'll give it a shot! Thanks!

Comment: This throws `Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.lang.String to R`. It specifically doesn't like `.map(Release::getId())`

Comment: Does it matter if `.getId()` is inherited from a parent class for `Release.java`?

Comment: Why do you specify `Release::getId()`.  Method references have not to specify the parenthesis. So use : `Release::getId`

Comment: I think the format is a little off. This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41531330/584947 says the error is because `getId()` has no parameters. I've adjusted it to:

`.stream().map(r -> r.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: `Release::getId()` definitely throws a type-based error and isn't working. It causes `.collect(` to become red as the return type of the function then can't be collected.

Comment: `.stream().map(r -> r.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());` is SUPER close but it throws `Cannot collect because Set<T> does not conform to HashSet<String>`.

Comment: don't specify `Release::getId()` but `Release::getId()`. Please read carefully my edit. I am sure you will get it. But exceptions, you should program by interface. Favor `Set<String>` to `HashSet<String>` in your code. `Collectors.toSet()` follows this principle. So it returns a `Set<String>` declared type.

Comment: You're totally right David if I change the declared type from HashSet to Set then the code works. Also, because `getId()` is inherited it's slightly different as well. Here's the working code:

`Set<String> oldIds = lastPage.getPage().getContent().stream().map(Identifiable::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome :) But I don't understand why you have specified `Identifiable` in the method reference. I think that it is the parent class of `Release`. If I am right,  `getId()` is public and so you should not need to refer to the Parent class to use the `getId` method reference.

Comment: IntelliJ did a couple optimizations to my syntax and probably automatically inserted `Identifiable::getId()` instead of `Release::getId()` since it's defined in `Identifiable`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
    HashSet<String> oldIds = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<String> newIds = new HashSet<>();


    lastPage.getPage().getContent().forEach(r -> oldIds.add(r.getId())); // my first lambda :)
    lastPageAgain.forEach(r -> newIds.add(r.getId()));
```

The syntax is slightly different because `lastPage` and `lastPageAgain` are actually different types.

Comment: `forEach` is "the last resort" and not appropriate for the request.